# Set long list of column names of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, csv

I have two files, one is data.csv and other header.csv. How can I use the header.csv to set the column names of the data.frame read from the data.csv file.

This does not work:

```
data = read.table(path,  sep = ";", quote = "",
                  dec = ".", head=FALSE, fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
header = read.table(path_header,  sep = ";", quote = "",
                  dec = ".", head=FALSE, fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
colnames(data) <- header
```

And since I have more then 200 columns so not really convenient to use

```
colnames(data) <- c("A","B",...)
```

Comment: You probably need `colnames(data) <- colnames(header)` if the number of columns of `data` and `header` are same.

Comment: After `header = read.table(...)` the object `header` is a dataframe. For `colnames(data) <- ...` you need a character vector on the right hand side. Probably you want `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in  `header = read.table(...)` .

Comment: It does not work because both are data.frame.  You need to either `unlist` after using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.table` or read with `readLines`

Comment: thanks alot, stringsAsFactors=FALSE worked just fine.